# Jekyll on Github suddenly do not work because of 'nil' date

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

Well, I swear I changed no setting at all.

I setup my Jekyll blog, and it did work before.

Every time I want to write something new, I just copy and old post file, rename it to the current date and modify the content within it.

But just one day, after I push my new content to Github, I received an email, noticing me that

> The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:
>   The value 'nil' was passed to a date-related filter that expects valid dates in `/_layouts/post.html` or one of its layouts. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-date-is-not-a-valid-datetime/.
>   For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:
>   https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds

First, I did not modify `/_layouts/post.html`. Second, I do not use date info in YAML, because Jekyll already uses the strong name requirement like YY-MM-DD-title.md.

I am just some guy who wants to write something fun but knows little about IT tech. I searched the Jekyll doc, and read the post on StackOverflow like below:

> [Invalid date while building on Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595812/invalid-date-while-building-on-github-pages)

But as my `post.html` file content is different from that post, I do not know what I can do.

I built it on my Mac with `bundle exec Jekyll build`, it just shows the same information as the email

> $ bundle exec jekyll build
>   Configuration file: > /Users/zhanglidong/Documents/ASyncFiles/jetorz.github.io/_config.yml
>               Source: /Users/zhanglidong/Documents/ASyncFiles/jetorz.github.io
>          Destination: > /Users/zhanglidong/Documents/ASyncFiles/jetorz.github.io/_site
>    Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
>         Generating...
>     Liquid Exception: Invalid Date: 'nil' is not a valid datetime. in /_layouts/post.html
>                ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
>                       ------------------------------------
>                       Invalid Date: 'nil' is not a valid datetime.

My GitHub repo: https://github.com/jetorz/jetorz.github.io

My jekyll blog: https://jetorz.github.io/

How can I fix it? Any one who wants to help the pity me? :(

Answer (score 0):

Like answer above suggested,

I rechecked the link I provided:

> [Invalid date while building on Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595812/invalid-date-while-building-on-github-pages)

There is and `if` block outside the `<time>` part.

I do not know much about Liquid,

But I think it worth trying.

So I add this `if` to my `post.html` like below

```
{% if page.date %}
        <time datetime="{{ page.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">
          {% assign date_format = site.minima.date_format | default: "%b %-d, %Y" %}
          {{ page.date | date: date_format }}
        </time>
{% endif %}
```

I do not know exactly what it is about,

but It does work :)

Now again I can post my blog.